# Making an image from an URI as the background of a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the image's URI. The image is stored in the sdcard. Using the URI how can I make this image as the background of my relative layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
File imgFile = new  File(“/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg”);  
if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    layout.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

FYI, you can `getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of this static path of SD-Card

Comment: My URI is: file:///mnt/sdcard/shopfloor/backgroundimg0.png.

Comment: My URI is: file:///mnt/sdcard/shopfloor/backgroundimg0.png.
 
The imageFile doesn't seem to be created from such an URI.